# postgres sql query counting two sets of objects

Tags: postgresql, join

I have this join query below. I am having one issue with it. 
The shippedUnits column comes out wrong. It just counts the total items. The issue is I am counting two sets of objects that have everything in common except the shipped field.

```
SELECT count(*) as "units", (select count("EsnsVmas".*) from "EsnsVmas" where
      "EsnsVmas"."shipped" = false AND "EsnsVmas"."VmaId" = 2 AND "EsnsVmas"."approved" = 
       true) as "shippedUnits", "Vmas".*, "Vendors"."name" as "name", "EsnsVmas".id as    
       "OrderItemId", "PurchaseOrderItems"."price", "Grades"."name" as "vendorGrade", 
       "Items"."name" as "model", "Items".id as "ItemId", "Grades".id as "GradeId" 
FROM "Vmas" 
      JOIN "EsnsVmas" on ("EsnsVmas"."VmaId" = "Vmas".id) 
      JOIN "Esns" on ("EsnsVmas"."EsnId" = "Esns".id) 
      JOIN "PurchaseOrderItems"  on ("Esns"."PurchaseOrderItemId"  =  
            "PurchaseOrderItems".id) 
      JOIN "Items" on ("PurchaseOrderItems"."ItemId" = "Items".id) 
      JOIN "Grades" on ("PurchaseOrderItems"."GradeId" = "Grades".id) 
      JOIN "Vendors" on ("Vmas"."VendorId"  = "Vendors".id)
 WHERE "Vmas".id =2 AND "EsnsVmas"."approved" = true 
 GROUP BY "Vmas".id, "PurchaseOrderItems".id, "Grades".id, "Items".id, "Vendors".id, "EsnsVmas".id ;
```

Comment: It appears that there is no relation between the query for shippedUnits and the outer query - ie, it will produce the same value in all rows. Is that what it is supposed to do? Or is the subquery supposed to vary per row?

Comment: its supposed to vary per row. ShippedUnits is just EsnsVmas that are approved and shipped. Units is just EsvVmas that are approved and not shipped. Your point about relationship is correct actually. But that is only because i modified the question and took out a bunch of other joins and fields that i thought werent necessary.

Comment: Do i need to add them back in? or you can answer the question of how to do two counts with those fields using joins in this fashion

Comment: it might help to see the original query. Also, since you have the group by clause - doesn't having the VMAS.* in the select give you a "must appear in the GROUP BY clause" error?

Comment: no thats fine. But please check the full query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still seems that there is no relation between the inner and outer queries other than the hardcoded VmaId = "2". Since I don't have the tables in a database I can't test to make sure it works - but here's my first shot at a possible fix:

```
SELECT count(*) as "units", (select count("EsnsVmas".*) from "EsnsVmas" e2 where
      e2."shipped" = false AND e2."VmaId" = "Vmas".id AND e2."approved" = 
       true AND "EsnsVmas".id = e2.id) as "shippedUnits", "Vmas".*, "Vendors"."name" as "name", "EsnsVmas".id as    
       "OrderItemId", "PurchaseOrderItems"."price", "Grades"."name" as "vendorGrade", 
       "Items"."name" as "model", "Items".id as "ItemId", "Grades".id as "GradeId" 
FROM "Vmas" 
      JOIN "EsnsVmas" on ("EsnsVmas"."VmaId" = "Vmas".id) 
      JOIN "Esns" on ("EsnsVmas"."EsnId" = "Esns".id) 
      JOIN "PurchaseOrderItems"  on ("Esns"."PurchaseOrderItemId"  =  
            "PurchaseOrderItems".id) 
      JOIN "Items" on ("PurchaseOrderItems"."ItemId" = "Items".id) 
      JOIN "Grades" on ("PurchaseOrderItems"."GradeId" = "Grades".id) 
      JOIN "Vendors" on ("Vmas"."VendorId"  = "Vendors".id)
 WHERE "Vmas".id =2 AND "EsnsVmas"."approved" = true 
 GROUP BY "Vmas".id, "PurchaseOrderItems".id, "Grades".id, "Items".id, "Vendors".id, "EsnsVmas".id ;
```

This changed two things. First was relating back with `"EsnsVmas".id = e2.id` at the end of the subselect (I aliased the EsnsVmas table in the subselect to `e2`). The other thing was changing `e2."VmaId" = "Vmas".id` (instead of hardcoding it to 2) which shouldn't affect the output but allows you to change the id in only one place.

Comment: yes thats great thank you very much. One last thing. How do i get shippedUnits to =0 if the count is 0

Comment: its hard coded to 2 here but in actuality that number is dynamically generated

Comment: The count function should return 0 if no records are returned. But, if it is not you could try to either to 0 + (select ...) to force it to a number, or use a case statement to match what you are receiving and return 0 in that case. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-conditional.html  One of those two should work.